# Setting an environment variable before a command in bash

Tags: macos, bash, environment-variables, sh

I am working on some installation of the MPC library and I came accross this command line (called "the initial command" afterwards) :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gnu/gmp-6.0.0/lib:/usr/local/gnu/mpfr-3.1.2/lib ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gnu/mpc-1.0.3 --with-gmp=/usr/local/gnu/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/gnu/mpfr-3.1.2
```

where `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set and where the configure command

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gnu/mpc-1.0.3 --with-gmp=/usr/local/gnu/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/gnu/mpfr-3.1.2
```

is executed after. Note that after the initial line, there is another line of the same type, with another setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and another command.

As I understand it, the initial line is equivalent to

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gnu/gmp-6.0.0/lib:/usr/local/gnu/mpfr-3.1.2/lib
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gnu/mpc-1.0.3 --with-gmp=/usr/local/gnu/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/gnu/mpfr-3.1.2
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Am I wrong ? If so, if I want to put the initial command in a .sh file, I only have to replace it by the three previous lines, right ? If not, how could I do it ?

Comment: It's not really equivalent, in that after the command is executed the variable is not unset, but restored to its previous value. Try it: `a=hello; a=goodbye printenv a; echo "$a"`. Now, in a script, the modifications made to a variable are not seen by the parent shell, so you don't really care about the `unset` part anyway (provided your script only does that, and that it is executed and not sourced).

Comment: Oh ok. SO, instead of just doing `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I could do it and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` right after to its previous value, value that I would have stored before having modified it. Is there an elegant way of doing this ? What do you mean by "executed and not sourced" ? (I am really interested in the script strict equivalent of the initial command line.)

Comment: I don't know about elegance. But what you can do is: 1. Not bother about setting back to its original value, since you'll be running a script, and as I said in my previous comment, modifications of variables in script are not seen by parent shell. 2. You do bother (why?) about setting back to its original value: so just wrap it in a subshell: use parentheses: `( export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...; ./configure ...)`. 3. Otherwise it's tricky to save the value of the variable and restore it: you also have to save whether it was set or not…

Comment: Why would you not simply put the "initial command" in the script?

Comment: @tripleee putting `foo=/usr/bin echo ${foo}` in a sh file and running it prints nothing on my mac's terminal.

Comment: That's because the shell evaluates the command (and thus expands the variable) before running it. Try `foo=/usr/bin perl -le 'print $ENV{"foo"}'` instead.

Comment: or `foo=/usr/bin eval 'echo "$foo"'`.

Comment: Certain [special built-in commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), including `eval`, are also supposed to leave the variable set after the command completes. However, `bash` only does this if it is in POSIX mode (`set -o posix`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are slightly wrong. The export makes the setting available for all commands and subprocesses in the current shell. Setting it on the command line sets it only for the duration of that command.

If you are writing a shell script, it's quite normal to set the variable and export it once, so you don't have to do it on each line. The value will only be in effect during the execution of the shell script<sup>1</sup>. It won't affect the parent process that calls the shell script, only the commands within the shell script. You won't need to unset the value at the end of the shell script.

<sup>1</sup> assuming you aren't running the shell script with `.` or `source`.

Comment: So, imagine I am doing two command lines : `foo=/usr/bin cmd1` and then `foo=/tmp/foo cmd2` where `foo` is an environment variable having already a value, let's say `/usr/local/lib`, before the execution of the two command. After each command `echo`ing `foo` would print `/usr/local/lib`. (Just tested it in a terminal.) Now, how could I reproduce the two command lines (and `foo`'s behaviour wrt them) in an `file.sh` file, that I'd run as follows : `./file.sh` ? (As you may guess, I don't want other commands executed in the sh file to be perturbated by bad values of `foo` ...

Comment: Anything you can do on the command line can be put in a script, and vice versa.

Comment: @tripleee I don't know that for sure, but if it is true, the command line cannot be pasted as it is in the script (`foo=/usr/bin echo ${foo}`...). I understand it can be done, but I don't want to resort to perl (as you showed in a comment to my question) for now, as I am fairly new to *nix word -- I want to keep it simple.

Comment: @user10000100_u: you would do it in a script exactly the same way as a terminal. There is absolutely no difference between the two.